# How to block "Test Certificate Info" request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, testing, certificate

Continuously comes from the "Test Certificate Info" request to our website.
I want to block the request by IIS.I tried to block on URL rewrite module in IIS but it was not enough.

> requested url : https://www.example.com/https:/www.example.com/
>   exception
>   : HttpException:  Message : A potentially dangerous Request.Path value
>   was detected from the client (:).

Do you have any solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever resolve this, i'm experiencing it too.

Comment: You could add a request filter in IIS to block the user-agent. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556542/2596048